# How do I return a JSON updated document in Oracle?

Tags: json, oracle

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/updating-json-document-json-merge-patch.html#GUID-31F88F28-3D92-489B-9CCD-BD1931B91F1F) I see an example:

```
SELECT json_mergepatch(po_document, '{"Special Instructions":null}'
                       RETURNING CLOB PRETTY)
  FROM j_purchaseorder;
```

But When I try this code in SQL Developer I get a squiggly line under CLOB and an error when I run the query?

Comment: Which version of oracle are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

It works in Oracle 18c:

```sql
SELECT json_mergepatch(
         po_document,
         '{"Special Instructions":null}'
         RETURNING CLOB PRETTY
       ) AS updated_po_document
FROM   j_purchaseorder;
```

Which for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE j_purchaseorder( po_document CLOB CHECK ( po_document IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO j_purchaseorder ( po_document )
  VALUES ( '{"existing":"value", "Special Instructions": 42}' );
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | UPDATED_PO_DOCUMENT              |
> | :------------------------------- |
> | {<br>  "existing" : "value"<br>} |
> ```

Removing the `Special Instructions` attribute as per the documentation you linked to:

> When merging object members that have the same field:
>
> - If the patch field value is `null` then the field is dropped from the source — it is not included in the result.
> - Otherwise, the field is kept in the result, but its value is the result of merging the source field value with the patch field value. That is, the merging operation in this case is recursive — it dives down into fields whose values are themselves objects.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=119b69bd61049f5dad0a68bc883e2a03)*

Comment: The [Changes in Oracle 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/changes.html#GUID-89DFFB5F-7C4F-4D01-8453-4F90C841070F) documentation lists `JSON_MERGEPATCH` as a new feature for that release; so if you are using an earlier version then it might not work. Confusingly, however, it seems to work on db<>fiddle, which is using Oracle 18.